# Show pdf table header only for first table on a page

Tags: java, itext

I have PDF document generated by iText in Java application, where I have a lot of tables with the same columns. In order to save some space in document I would like to have header only the first table on page. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have 2 tables. The first table has column lable whereas the rest column headers removed?

Comment: In that case: don't repeat the header. Can you give a better description of the problem? Right now, it sounds like a non-issue because repeating headers don't just happen: you cause them to happen.

Comment: @Bruno I don't think the OP has a single table but multiple ones and if more than one of those tables are on the same page, only the top one shall have headers.